# How to remove replace part of a string?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

We have an input from user who provides source account ID and DB ID. Problem here is the input will be: `[222].[2]`. I need to filter the first `[222]` as source account id, second value in[2] as DB ID.

**Input**

```
[222].[2] ([srcacct id].[database id])
```

We need to remove braces `"["` and `"."`.

**Output**

```
Source Account id=222, DBID=2
```

PS: In sql i have a function which return the expected value, but i am not familiar with Oracle and need some inputs on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? hint: substr, instr

Comment: i have a function to do this in sql but i am not familiar with Oracle.if you need my sql query i can provide the same.

Comment: `Instr` and `substr` can be useful; another approach could be by `regexp_substr`. Try something and them, if you have an issue with your code, feel free to ask for help

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression is quite simple in this case; take the first number for the *source account*, and the second one for the *DBID* - it is the last parameter of the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function.

For example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '[222].[2] ([srcacct id].[database id])' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1) source_account,
  4         regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2) dbid
  5  from test;

SOU D
--- -
222 2

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: a variable]**

That depends on a client tool you use. In SQL*Plus, you'd use `'&&col`' (or whatever name you want to give) and run

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL> select regexp_substr('&&col', '\d+', 1, 1) source_account,
  2         regexp_substr('&&col', '\d+', 1, 2) dbid
  3  from dual;
Enter value for col: [222].[2] ([srcacct id].[database id]

SOU D
--- -
222 2

SQL> undefine col
```

A the end, undefine it because "&&" would keep its value *forever*.

---

Anyway, if you want to "pass" something and "return" the result, consider writing a **function** instead. It works everywhere. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_ret (par_input in varchar2)
  2    return varchar2
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    return 'Source account ID = ' || regexp_substr(par_input, '\d+', 1, 1) ||
  6           ', DBID = '            || regexp_substr(par_input, '\d+', 1, 2);
  7  end;
  8  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_ret('[222].[2] ([srcacct id].[database id])') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source account ID = 222, DBID = 2

SQL>
```

**[EDIT #2: a lookup table]**

Code you wrote (as a comment) won't compile; you can't do it that way. Here's an example of how it might look like. I can't test it right now; do it yourself.

```
create or replace function f_ret (par_input in varchar2)
  return varchar2
is
  l_source_account_id number;
  l_dbid              number;
  retval              varchar2(200);
begin
  l_source_account_id := regexp_substr(par_input, '\d+', 1, 1);
  l_dbid              := regexp_substr(par_input, '\d+', 1, 2);

  select count(*)
    into l_cnt
    from accounts_table
    where srcaccountid = l_source_account_id;

  if l_cnt > 0 then
     retval := 'Source account ID = ' || regexp_substr(par_input, '\d+', 1, 1) ||
               ', DBID = '            || regexp_substr(par_input, '\d+', 1, 2);
  end if;

  return retval;            
end;
```

Comment: I have tried this below: DEF  accountid varchar(40): = ('[123].[2].[2]');
select regexp_substr(@accountid, '\d+', 1, 1) source_account_id,
regexp_substr(@accountid, '\d+', 1, 2) Database_id,
regexp_substr(@accountid, '\d+', 1, 3) levelid

from dual; 
 
and i'm getting missing expression error.

Comment: i need to know how to declare that value as avariable and need to pass to get the result

Comment: I choose the last one (function). and what i need is, i have a table(source account id,account id,db id columns) now, i need to filter source account id and return only the account id based on the input source account value.

Comment: Feel free to do so.

Comment: i have tried this:                SQL> create or replace function get_accountdetails (par_input in varchar2)
     return varchar2
   is
   begin
     
  'Source_Account_ID = ' || regexp_substr(par_input, '\d+', 1, 1) ||
            ', DBID = '            || regexp_substr(par_input, '\d+', 1, 2) ||
   ',Account_Level    = ' || regexp_substr(par_input, '\d+', 1, 3); 
   
   return 'Account_id ='select account_id from table a where srcaccountid=Source_Account_ID
  
   end;
   /

Comment: But getting error, could you please help me there where i'm doing wrong

Comment: I posted EDIT #2, check what it says.